# "PHP Warning: fopen(/app/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /app/vendor/google/cloud/src/Storage/StorageObject.php on line 585"

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, fopen, silex, storage

tengo un problema de permisos intentando descargar un archivo de Google Cloud Storage utilizando PHP en un método de una API que recibe llamada desde una App.

Para asegurarme, he creado una cuenta de servicio, le he asignado el rol de administrador y he usado el archivo .json con las claves de esta cuenta de servicio para autenticarme al crear el cliente de Storage. Luego en la llamada le paso por parámetros los datos del archivo (que he puesto publico por si acaso) y la ruta, pero da igual la ruta que pruebe sale siempre el mismo error.

El código de mi App que afecta a este método es el siguiente:

```
<?php
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;


// Crea la aplicacion de SILEX
$app = new Application();


//Descarga el archivo seleccionado de un siniestro.
$app->get('/download_archivos_siniestro_app', function () use ($app) {

    $ARCH=$_REQUEST['Archivo'];
    $destination=$_REQUEST['Ruta'];


    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; 

    $path = "credenciales.json";
    $keyFile = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
    $projectId = "mi_ID_del_proyecto";

    $storage = new StorageClient($config = ['projectId' => $projectId, $keyFile]);

    $bucketName = "mi_bucket";
    $objectName = $ARCH;

    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->object($objectName);
    $object->downloadToFile(__DIR__ .$destination);

    $respuesta=array();
    $respuesta['status']='0';
    $respuesta['message']='Todo correcto!';
        }
    }
    return $app->json($respuesta);
});


// Funcion para devolver la instancia del PDO
$app['database'] = function () use ($app) {
    // Connect to CloudSQL from App Engine.
    $dsn = getenv('MYSQL_DSN');
    $user = getenv('MYSQL_USER');
    $password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
    if (!isset($dsn, $user) || false === $password) {
        throw new Exception('Set MYSQL_DSN, MYSQL_USER, and MYSQL_PASSWORD environment variables');
    }

    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    return $db;
};


// Acepta peticiones JSON
$app->before(function (Request $request) {
    if (0 === strpos($request->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'application/json')) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $request->request->replace(is_array($data) ? $data : array());
    }
});

return $app;
?>
```

Cuando le paso en la llamada los parametros archivo y destino lo hago de este modo:

```
https://midominiodegoogle.appspot.com/download_archivos_siniestro_app?Archivo=image.jpg&Ruta=/image.jpg
```

Una vez hecha esta llamada recibo el siguiente error en el log de la consola:

```
"PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(/app/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /app/vendor/google/cloud/src/Storage/StorageObject.php on line 585"
```

Los demas metodos de la API funcionan sin problema, los errores vienen simplemente de no poder colocar el archivo que se intenta descargar en ninguna de las carpetas especificadas.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Parece que la carpeta `app/vendor/google/cloud/src/Storage/` no tiene los permisos adecuados. Prueba a darles permiso `755` a la carpeta `vendor` o a la carpeta `app`

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano , gracias por tu comentario. El caso es que al "desplegar" la App se crea dentro de Google Cloud la carpeta "app" a la cual creo que no puedo aceder para cambiar permisos. Estaba intentando apuntar fuera de esa carpeta de alguna forma pero no lo consigo.

Comment: Viendo más detenidamente el mensaje, percibo que el error ocurre intentando abrir este archivo: `fopen(/app/image.jpg)` ese archivo debe estar en una carpeta accesible.

Comment: @A.Cedano he probado con múltiples direcciones, incluso direcciones web, como error dice o bien que no tengo permiso, que la ruta no existe o que no puede acceder a direcciones web.

Comment: Pero el problema es donde usas el `fopen`, no veo esa línea en tu código ¿?

Comment: Ese código viene de la clase Storage client, el metodo es:                  `public function downloadToFile($path, array $options = [])
    {
        $destination = Psr7\stream_for(fopen($path, 'w'));

        Psr7\copy_to_stream(
            $this->downloadAsStream($options),
            $destination
        );

        $destination->seek(0);

        return $destination;
    }`

Comment: Pues eso, el problema es que no tienes permiso para abrir el archivo que se indica `$path`, entonces tienes que buscar la forma de que haya permiso para abrirlo, no hay otra.

Comment: Si, eso lo tengo claro, el problema sigue siendo que no encuentro el modo de cambiar los permisos de esta carpeta que se genera automáticamente y a la que no se puede acceder desde la consola de Google Cloud

Comment: Pero, ¿dónde se genera esa carpeta? ¿No tienes acceso a las carpetas para poder modificar sus permisos? entonces, mal asunto ¿no?

Comment: He buscado de todo lo que he podido tanto por la interfaz como por Internet y no hay manera de acceder a esas carpetas para controlar permisos. Así que si, bastante mal asunto... Seguiré intetandolo.

Comment: Generalmente en tu entorno deberías tener privilegios para otorgar permisos a carpetas. Quizá es que no lo estés haciendo del modo correcto. Si es así, dinos en qué entorno está la carpeta realmente si en el servidor (PHP), en Google Cloud  o dónde...

Comment: He estado trabajando en un método para subir archivos, que me daba el mismo tipo de error, y he conseguido solucionar esa parte, había que poner como objetivo guardarlo en una variable tipo archivo y desde ahí sacarlo al equipo desde el que se ejecute, estoy intentando hacer lo mismo con este método, a ver si lo consigo y pongo la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente la respuesta es que era necesario crear un archivo temporal en el que guardar lo que enviaba la función downloadToFile, de esta forma con ese archivo temporal se puede forzar una descarga en php con readfile(). La parte del codigo que habia que modificar era esta.

```
        $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
        $object = $bucket->object($objectName);
        $nombre_fichero_tmp = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");
        $object->downloadToFile($nombre_fichero_tmp);


        if (file_exists($nombre_fichero_tmp)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($nombre_fichero_tmp));
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($objectName).'"');//inline hace que se vea en linea, attachment hace que se descargue.
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($nombre_fichero_tmp));
            readfile($nombre_fichero_tmp);
            exit;
        } 

        unlink($nombre_fichero_tmp);
```

Gracias a todos por vuestra colaboración.